# Generating URLs for ASP.NET MVC Area routing with subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an ASP.NET MVC app which has areas with special routes as following:

Area registration file:

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "AccessControlApi_default",
    "accesscontrol/api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

context.MapRoute(
    "AccessControl_dashboardwidgets",
    "accesscontrol/dashboardwidgets/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "AccessControl.Controllers.DashboardWidgets" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "AccessControl_default",
    "accesscontrol/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "AccessControl.Controllers" }
);
```

First routing is for api, second is for controllers and views in a sub-folder under the area, and third is for the default controllers under area.

Everything is working well with routing, but the issue is with the use of `Url.Action` like this one:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index","Home",new{area="AccessControl"})'>Go to home</a>
```

It's always injecting **dashboardwidgets** keyword in the url between area and controller like this: **{host}/accesscontrol/*dashboardwidgets*/Home/Index**

How can I generate urls according to my needs, either to root of area, or to this sub folder under the area??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution would be to use named routes in constructing your links. You would need to switch the call from

```
@Url.Action("Index","Home",new{area="AccessControl"})
```

to

```
@Url.RouteUrl("AccessControl_dashboardwidgets", new {area = "AccessControl", controller="Home", action="Index"})
```

or

```
@Url.RouteUrl("AccessControl_default", new {area = "AccessControl", controller="Home", action="Index"})
```

Depending on which route you are aiming for.

Sorry about the confusion with the parameters, was editing while doing something else... multitasking on Monday morning is obviously to be avoided:)

Comment: it is generating the full anchor, not only the url?

Comment: According to MSDN they both generate a fully qualified URL see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper_methods(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Url.Action will return just the url, while Html.RouteLink will return the full anchor starting from <a href="....

Comment: Try route RouteUrl instead. Sorry missed the subtle difference :)

Comment: Remove second parameter also in RouteUrl function please

Comment: Lol, no need for area at all while it is already included in the route definition, so remove it completely please :)

Comment: Left in there on purpose to show that it can be defined in the dictionary as well even though not needed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use @Url.Action extension method you need to specify httproute name for routeValues parameter like that:

```
@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { httproute ="AccessControlApi_default"} )
```